# Regular Expression match everything but two names and <email address> after particular word

Tags: regex, expression, match, names, regex-lookarounds

I have a bunch of Names and email addresses inside of these aggregated emails and I'd like to get rid of everything but the `First Last <email@domain.com>` throughout the document.  Basically I have...

```
From: Name Wood <email@gmail.com>
Subject: Yelp entries for iPod contest
Date: April 20, 2012 12:51:07 PM EDT
To: email@domain.cc

Have had a great experience with .... My Son ... is currently almost a year into treatment. Dr. ... is great! Very informative and always updates us on progress and we have our regular visits. The ... buck program is a great incentive which they've implemented to help kids take care of their teeth/braces. They also offer payment programs which help for those of us that need a structured payment option. Wouldn't take my kids anywhere else. Thanks Dr. ... and staff
Text for 1, 2, and 3 entries to Yelp
Hope ... wins!!
Begin forwarded message:

From: Name Wood <email@gmail.com>
Subject: reviews 2 and 3
Date: April 20, 2012 12:44:26 PM EDT
To: email@domain.cc

Have had a great experience with ... Orthodontics. My Son ... is currently almost a year into treatment. Dr. ... is great! Very informative and always updates us on progress and we have our regular visits. The ... buck program is a great incentive which they've implemented to help kids take care of their teeth/braces. They also offer payment programs which help for those of us that need a structured payment option. Wouldn't take my kids anywhere else. Thanks Dr. ... and staff
Have had a great experience with...
```

I want to only match the...

```
Name Wood <email@gmail.com>
Name Wood <email@gmail.com>
```

from this text.  So basically I want to match next two words after the word `"From: "` plus `"<"+email address+">"` excluding the word `"From: "`.  I've gleaned from researching that this is a negative lookahead (I think) searching for two whole words (somehow using `{0,2}`) and then an email address from one `<` character to another `>`.

Comment: What regex implementation are you going to use? Perl? Python? Java? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You could just do this:

```
/(?:From: )(.*)/g
```

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression will find what you're looking for:

```
(?<=From:)\s*[^<]+<[^>]+>
```

But what you're going to do with it is a little unclear from your question. The matched text should probably be put into one or more groups so you can extract the text you want. (Name in one group? Email in a separate group? Or both together?) You haven't said what you want to do with it, so you'll have to provide more information. The above is the simplest case scenario.

Explanation:

```
(?<=From:)   # positive lookbehind to find "From:"
\s*          # optional whitespace
[^<]+<       # everything up to the first '<' (the name)
[^>]+>       # everything up to the '>' (the email)
```

Comment: OK this is perfect, now I want to do something else with that selection, is there a way to reverse this and select everything but this selection?

Comment: In a word, no. What are you really trying to do? Strip out names and email addresses and keep everything else? Your question says _get rid of everything but the "First Last " throughout the document_. Now you're saying something different.

Comment: Just that, I'd like to apply this regular expression, hit "delete" and be left with just the names and addresses of the people.  If not, then maybe I can create a form that will accept this in a text area and then output the result of the regular expression in a separate area.

Comment: Again, you haven't said what tool you're using. Is it some text editor? Regex allows you to find what you want (name/email), extract it, massage it, replace or whatever. Regex does not allow you to find what you want, and delete everything else. You're not a programmer, are you? (and that wasn't meant to be mean :-)

Comment: @alan - Should be able to strip a string of what you don't want with something like global find `.*?(<want>)|.*$` and replace `$1`.

Comment: I'm using the regex find function of Espresso (by MacRabbit) for now but later I'd like to use a web form to pull out the info.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to strip all but the name and email.
Modifier 's' (dot includes newline),
Global find and replacement for both regex's is `$1\n`

This is faster but will leave an extra newline on sucesses.

```
Find .*?From:[^\S\n]*([^<\n]+<[^>\n]*\@[^>\n]*>)|.*$
```

This is slower (uses lookahead) but won't leave the extra newline.

```
Find  .*?From:[^\S\n]*([^<\n]+<[^>\n]*\@[^>\n]*>)(?:(?!From:[^\S\n]*[^<\n]+<[^>\n]*\@[^>\n]*>).)*
```